# Limit selectable divs in a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to create a product feature selection page where the user needs to select 3 features out of 6. Now, I got to a point where I can limit the number of selectable elements so if 3 elements are selected, the user wont be able to select a 4th one.

I need to modify this so when the user is attempting to select the 4th element, the 1st element they selected becomes unselected and the 4th element becomes selected. I hope it makes sense.

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  var $et = $(e.target);
  if ($et.hasClass('fill')) {
    $et.removeClass('fill');
  } else {
    if ($('.fill').length < 2) {
      $et.addClass('fill');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">one</div>
<div id="2">two</div>
<div id="3">three</div>
<div id="4">four</div>
```

This fiddle shows where I'm at with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/MarKP/32/

This fiddle is not mine, but this is exactly what I have right now in my project.

I'm trying to get this done using jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can maintain an array which holds the order in which the elements were clicked. Then, when the limit is hit, you can remove the class from the element which was selected first. Try this:

```js
var selections = [];

var $div = $('div').click(function(e) {
  selections.push(this.id);
  if (selections.length > 3)
    selections.shift(); // remove first item
    
  setState();
});

function setState() {
  $div.removeClass('fill');
  $div.filter(`#${selections.join(',#')}`).addClass('fill');
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">one</div>
<div id="2">two</div>
<div id="3">three</div>
<div id="4">four</div>
<div id="5">five</div>
<div id="6">six</div>
```

Finally, note that jQuery 1.4.4 is massively outdated; nearly 10 years in fact. You need to update it.

Comment: I think thats it, thank you! Just gonna make it so if you click on a div that is selected, it simply unselects it.